# How to beat asynchronous issues in Firebase with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

So I am sending over an image to my storage with imageURl, but when I try to post that imageURL to the FIRDataBase it either gets put in as "" or when I set some conditional logic to see if an image has been selected I have to do the first login process twice, can anyone help me out the issue is in the `getUserNameAlert()` function I believe:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage{
            let imguid = NSUUID().uuidString
            let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

             var userImagesRef = DataService.ds.REF_USER_IMAGES.child(imguid).put(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print("AA: able to upload image to FIREBASE STORAGE")
                }else{
                    print("GREAT SUCCESS FOR THE STORAGE")
                    imageSelected = true
                    let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    if let url = downloadURL{
                        userImageURL = url
                    }
                }
             })

        }else{
            print("AA: Valid image wasn't selected")
        }
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


 func getUserNameAlert(user:FIRUser, provider: String){

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create a User Name", message: "Enter Your Desired User Name", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter User Name"
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Create", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    if let textFields = alert.textFields{
                        let theTextFields = textFields as! [UITextField]
                        userName = theTextFields[0].text!
                        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        if imageSelected == true{
                        self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userdata: ["provider":provider,"userName":userName,"imageURL":userImageURL])
                        }
                    }

                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

and the userNameURL is a global variable of type String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in these lines...

```
self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion:     
if imageSelected == true {
 self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userdata: ["provider":provider,"userName":userName,"imageURL":userImageURL])
}
```

The issue is that your code is going to bring up the imagePicker, and then it's *immediately* going to run the next few lines to see if imageSelected == true. It's not going to wait until the user is done with the image picker, which is probably what you're hoping would happen.

There are lots of different ways you could address this, all depending on what your optimal user experience to be. But here's a couple of strategies you could try:

**Strategy one**: Move `completeSignIn` so that you're calling it in the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMedia...` method. You'll want to call it after you've successfully uploaded the image, when you have the downloadURL available. (Then, to be complete, you'll also need to call it in your `imagePickerController: didCancel` method.) This will work, but has the disadvantage that you won't be able to call `completeSignIn` until after the image is uploaded, which might take a long time on slow networks.

**Strategy two:** Run `completeSignIn` like you're currently doing, but then retroactively adjust the current user's `imageURL` when you're all done retrieving it from the upload method. How that would work specifically depends quite a bit on what you're doing in your `completeSignIn` call.

This has the advantage that you're no longer blocking your call by waiting for the user to upload a giant image. It will mean more work for you, however, to make sure you're adjusting the right imageURL for the right user (although I'm guessing you're not swapping out users super-frequently in your app), and to watch out for other weird cases that might arise if this upload call completes at a time you weren't expecting.